# "What I want is that X do(es) something" vs. "What I want is for X to do something"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, subjunctive-mood

**Example**

Alice: *What do you want?*
Bob: *Do you know what I want? What I want is ...*

- **that** Peter **makes** the phone call (*that + present simple*)
- **that** Peter **make** the phone call (*that + present subjunctive*)
- **for** Peter **to make** the phone call (*for + infinitive*)

More generally, which of the following constructions is correct/preferred and why?

- What I want is that X does something.
- What I want is that X do something.
- What I want is for X to do something.

Comment: Here speaking with native speakers would help you. Out of hand I would go with number 2. For a long drawn out process "to verb" may be more commonplace as in "for Peter to start preparing for his upcoming interview".

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't much like any of these, which all sound a bit affected/rhetorical. You can search Google Books or the internet for examples, but on a brief search of Google Books I only found examples of "What I want is for..." and "What I want is that X should..."